# Detection of rectangles using Hough Transformation. Encountered this error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, numpy

my code looks like this, getting NoneType error for lines[0] and not able to find why exactly its None type.:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image=cv2.imread('img.jpg',0)
edges = cv2.Canny(img,50,150,apertureSize = 3)
lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges,1,np.pi/180,200)
for rho,theta in lines[0]:   # Error was said to be in this line 
    a = np.cos(theta)
    b = np.sin(theta)
    x0 = a*rho
    y0 = b*rho
    x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
    y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
    x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
    y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))

cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255),1)
cv2.imshow('image',image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that no lines were detected. Do check the result of cv2.Canny using cv2.imshow to see if any straight edges are there. The threshold parameter of HoughLines can be reduced to allow more lines to be detected.

Edit: I tested the code with the image that you sent. The threshold for HoughLines (200) was way too high, because the edges detected by Canny are usually not continuous. Given that the image is only 200 pixels high, I recommend a value between 50 and 100.

Herewith find the sample code after editing:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image=cv2.imread('/home/foo/Downloads/image_barcode.jpg',0)
edges = cv2.Canny(image,50,150,apertureSize = 3)
lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges,1,np.pi/180,70) # used to be 200
for rho,theta in lines[0]:   # displays only the first line 
    a = np.cos(theta)
    b = np.sin(theta)
    x0 = a*rho
    y0 = b*rho
    x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
    y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
    x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
    y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))

cv2.line(image,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(255,0,255),1)
cv2.imshow('image',image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByN-oisJmRd2amx0MUgzRUZOdW8/view?usp=sharing

Sorry for the late reply.